nodisplayskipstretch and setdisplayskipstretch not working with setspace and cases environment
I am trying to use the cases environment in a double-spaced document, but the bracket is persistently too large. Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\setstretch{2}
\begin{document}
\[
    x = \begin{cases}
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4
    \end{cases}
\]
\begin{equation*}
    x = \begin{cases}
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\begin{singlespace}
    \[
        x = \begin{cases}
            1 & 2 \\
            3 & 4
        \end{cases}
    \]
\end{singlespace}
\end{document}


I would like the first two to display in the same way as the third.
Many thanks!

That's a different issue that has nothing to do with nodisplayskipstretch

If you want to reduce the baseline stretch only for cases see, the answer to Parenthesis vertically misaligned in "cases" environment. If you want all displayed math environments to be singlespaced you can use:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{mwe}
\setstretch{2}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[
    x = \begin{cases}
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4
    \end{cases}
\]
\begin{equation*}
    x = \begin{cases}
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\begin{singlespace}
    \[
        x = \begin{cases}
            1 & 2 \\
            3 & 4
        \end{cases}
    \]
\end{singlespace}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}


Note: nodisplayskipstretch influences only the space before and after displayed math but not inside.

Amazing - \everydisplay was exactly what I was after. Thanks!
